# Creating table that I can modify column size and use multiple pages

Tags: tables

I am currently trying to create a table that has a lot of content in it. I have tried two methods and either the table runs off the end of the page, or it runs off the side of the page and the formatting changes. I haven't been able to combine the two methods to get it to work.

**Method 1:** Table formatting looks good but it does not support multiple pages.

```
\begin{longtable}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |c||c|X|c| } 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Event}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Panellist}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Role}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Organization}}       \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Ecosystem Partner Marketing Roundtable} 
    & Mark Lafrate & Product marketing manager for Apps \& partnerships & Intercom \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Katie Rubak & Sr. manager of partner marketing & Talkdesk \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Briarley Laban & Global Director of partner marketing & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Morgan Rochofski & Product and partner marketing & Salesloft                        \tabularnewline \hline
   
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Leaders of Larger Ecosystems Roundtable} 
    & Scott Brinker & VP of platform ecosystem & HubSpot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Bader Hamdan & Head of platform partnerships & Twilio \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Shay Howe & SVP of platform strategy & ActiveCampaign \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Heidi Williams & Head of platform engineering & Grammarly                           \tabularnewline \hline
  
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Prioritize SaaS Product Integrations Roundtable} 
    & Richard O'Connell & Director of product partnerships & Atlassian \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Amanda Groves & Director of product marketing & Crossbeam \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Chris Lavoie & Sr. technology partner manager & Gorgias \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kabir Mathur & Head of product partnerships & Typeform                              \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Build a API and Integrations Roadmap} 
    & Chloe Wu & Product manager & Gusto \\\cline{2-4} 
    & India Anderson & Sr. manager, product management integrations & Avalara \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Deven Ravel & Head of technology partnerships & Reputation \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Marum & Director of ISV alliances & SugarCRM                                     \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Cross-functional collaboration in tech partnerships} 
    & Roger Haas & Sr. manager of technology partnerships & Pantheon.io \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Jamie Boardman & Director of partnerships, product & Mailchimp \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kenneth Marks & Associate Director of product management & Olo \\\cline{2-4}  
    & John Greene & Director of engineering, integrations & Airship                           \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Advice for Building a Tech Partner Program} 
    & Jaimie Fucillo & VP of Partnerships & Mindbody \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Daniel O'Leary & Director of Partnerships & Box \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Jake Wallace & Head of global technology partnerships & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Elliot Smith & Head of partnerships & 6sense                                        \tabularnewline \hline
        
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Tackle Tech Partner Operations} 
    & Megha Bhatt & Partnerships lead of operations \& strategy operations & Shopify \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Greg Mitchell & Partner programs and operations & Starburst \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Irving & Sr. Manager of global partner programs \& strategy & WP Engine \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Manishi Singh & SVP of app orchestration & Spryker Systems                          \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Build a Platform UX Partners and Customers Love} 
    & Richard Fortune & Product manager of platform experience & Xero \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Courtney George & Head of design for data & Amplitude \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kirby Montgomery & VP of product leadership & C2FO \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Ashwini Sriram & Group product manager & Twilio                                     \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{SaaS Ecosystem Alliance Events}
\label{SaaSEA}
\end{longtable}
```

This comes out as:
[image]

**Method 2:** The table fits multiple pages but incorrect formatting as it runs off the right side of the page

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}

\caption{SaaS Ecosystem Alliance Events}\\
\hline
\textbf{Event} & \textbf{Panellist} & \textbf{Role} & \textbf{Organization} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Event} & \textbf{Panellist} & \textbf{Role} & \textbf{Organization} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

    \multirow{4}{6em}{Ecosystem Partner Marketing Roundtable} 
    & Mark Lafrate & Product marketing manager for Apps \& partnerships & Intercom \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Katie Rubak & Sr. manager of partner marketing & Talkdesk \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Briarley Laban & Global Director of partner marketing & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Morgan Rochofski & Product and partner marketing & Salesloft                        \tabularnewline \hline
   
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Leaders of Larger Ecosystems Roundtable} 
    & Scott Brinker & VP of platform ecosystem & HubSpot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Bader Hamdan & Head of platform partnerships & Twilio \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Shay Howe & SVP of platform strategy & ActiveCampaign \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Heidi Williams & Head of platform engineering & Grammarly                           \tabularnewline \hline
  
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Prioritize SaaS Product Integrations Roundtable} 
    & Richard O'Connell & Director of product partnerships & Atlassian \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Amanda Groves & Director of product marketing & Crossbeam \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Chris Lavoie & Sr. technology partner manager & Gorgias \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kabir Mathur & Head of product partnerships & Typeform                              \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Build a API and Integrations Roadmap} 
    & Chloe Wu & Product manager & Gusto \\\cline{2-4} 
    & India Anderson & Sr. manager, product management integrations & Avalara \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Deven Ravel & Head of technology partnerships & Reputation \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Marum & Director of ISV alliances & SugarCRM                                     \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Cross-functional collaboration in tech partnerships} 
    & Roger Haas & Sr. manager of technology partnerships & Pantheon.io \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Jamie Boardman & Director of partnerships, product & Mailchimp \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kenneth Marks & Associate Director of product management & Olo \\\cline{2-4}  
    & John Greene & Director of engineering, integrations & Airship                           \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{Advice for Building a Tech Partner Program} 
    & Jaimie Fucillo & VP of Partnerships & Mindbody \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Daniel O'Leary & Director of Partnerships & Box \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Jake Wallace & Head of global technology partnerships & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Elliot Smith & Head of partnerships & 6sense                                        \tabularnewline \hline
        
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Tackle Tech Partner Operations} 
    & Megha Bhatt & Partnerships lead of operations \& strategy operations & Shopify \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Greg Mitchell & Partner programs and operations & Starburst \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Irving & Sr. Manager of global partner programs \& strategy & WP Engine \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Manishi Singh & SVP of app orchestration & Spryker Systems                          \tabularnewline \hline
    
    \multirow{4}{6em}{How to Build a Platform UX Partners and Customers Love} 
    & Richard Fortune & Product manager of platform experience & Xero \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Courtney George & Head of design for data & Amplitude \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kirby Montgomery & VP of product leadership & C2FO \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Ashwini Sriram & Group product manager & Twilio                                     \tabularnewline \hline
    
\caption{SaaS Ecosystem Alliance Events}
\label{SaaSEA}
\end{longtable}
```

Shown as:
[image]

Any help/ tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the first method, you could use the `xltabular` package  and  its eponymous environment, as it brings the long table functionalities to tabularx.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that one a try as well.

Comment: @beanstump - It's of course ok to upvote good answers, but the site guidelines strongly encourage users to hold off on "accepting" what may be the *best* answer for several hours, and maybe even a day or two. Why? Because accepting the very first answer within minutes of it being posted tends to discourage other would-be answer writers from providing their own, possibly even better, answers.

Comment: That is a very valid point. I will be aware of that moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple options, but in 2022 I recommend trying out the tabularray package's `longtblr` environment, which is quite powerful and customizable.

See the package's [extensive documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) for more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{longtblr}[
        caption={SaaS Ecosystem Alliance Events},
        label={SaaSEA}
    ]{
    colspec={|Q[wd=6em,halign=l]||c|X[halign=l]|c| },
    row{1}={font=\bfseries,halign=c},
    rowhead=1,
    stretch=1.5,
    }
    \hline
    Event & Panellist & Role & Organization \\ \hline
    
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{Ecosystem Partner Marketing Roundtable} 
    & Mark Lafrate & Product marketing manager for Apps \& partnerships & Intercom \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Katie Rubak & Sr. manager of partner marketing & Talkdesk \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Briarley Laban & Global Director of partner marketing & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Morgan Rochofski & Product and partner marketing & Salesloft \\ \hline
   
   \SetCell[r=4]{}{Leaders of Larger Ecosystems Roundtable} 
    & Scott Brinker & VP of platform ecosystem & HubSpot \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Bader Hamdan & Head of platform partnerships & Twilio \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Shay Howe & SVP of platform strategy & ActiveCampaign \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Heidi Williams & Head of platform engineering & Grammarly \\ \hline
  
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{How to Prioritize SaaS Product Integrations Roundtable} 
    & Richard O'Connell & Director of product partnerships & Atlassian \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Amanda Groves & Director of product marketing & Crossbeam \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Chris Lavoie & Sr. technology partner manager & Gorgias \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kabir Mathur & Head of product partnerships & Typeform \\ \hline
    
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{How to Build a API and Integrations Roadmap} 
    & Chloe Wu & Product manager & Gusto \\\cline{2-4} 
    & India Anderson & Sr. manager, product management integrations & Avalara \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Deven Ravel & Head of technology partnerships & Reputation \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Marum & Director of ISV alliances & SugarCRM \\ \hline
    
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{Cross-functional collaboration in tech partnerships} 
    & Roger Haas & Sr. manager of technology partnerships & Pantheon.io \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Jamie Boardman & Director of partnerships, product & Mailchimp \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kenneth Marks & Associate Director of product management & Olo \\\cline{2-4}  
    & John Greene & Director of engineering, integrations & Airship \\ \hline
    
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{Advice for Building a Tech Partner Program} 
    & Jaimie Fucillo & VP of Partnerships & Mindbody \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Daniel O'Leary & Director of Partnerships & Box \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Jake Wallace & Head of global technology partnerships & Trustpilot \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Elliot Smith & Head of partnerships & 6sense \\ \hline
        
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{How to Tackle Tech Partner Operations} 
    & Megha Bhatt & Partnerships lead of operations \& strategy operations & Shopify \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Greg Mitchell & Partner programs and operations & Starburst \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Matt Irving & Sr. Manager of global partner programs \& strategy & WP Engine \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Manishi Singh & SVP of app orchestration & Spryker Systems \\ \hline
    
    \SetCell[r=4]{}{How to Build a Platform UX Partners and Customers Love} 
    & Richard Fortune & Product manager of platform experience & Xero \\\cline{2-4} 
    & Courtney George & Head of design for data & Amplitude \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Kirby Montgomery & VP of product leadership & C2FO \\\cline{2-4}  
    & Ashwini Sriram & Group product manager & Twilio \\ \hline
    
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: longtblr example]

Comment: Thank you! longtblr using the package tabularray worked perfectly. Thanks for adding the documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest that you employ an `xltabular` environment. An `xltabular` is very much like a `longtable`, except that one can use the `X` column type defined by `tabularx` environment.

I would also like to encourage you to get rid of all vertical lines in a table and replacing horizontal lines with whitespace, to give the table a much more open and inviting "look".

As a result of making these changes, the table should fit on two pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
% note that 1+0.8+1.45+0.75=4= no. of X-type columns:
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L{1}M{0.8}L{1.45}L{0.75} @{}} 


%% headers and footers

\caption{SaaS Ecosystem Alliance Events}\label{SaaSEA} \\
\toprule
Event & Panelist & Role & Organization \\  
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace\toprule 
Event & Panelist & Role & Organization \\  
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small\itshape Continued on next page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


% body of table

    \mycell{Ecosystem Partner Marketing Roundtable}
    & Mark Lafrate & Product marketing manager for  apps \& partnerships & Intercom \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Katie Rubak & Sr.\ manager of partner marketing & Talkdesk \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Briarley Laban & Global Director of partner marketing & Trustpilot \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Morgan Rochofski & Product and partner marketing & Salesloft \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
   
    \mycell{Leaders of Larger Ecosystems Roundtable}
    & Scott Brinker & VP of platform ecosystem & HubSpot \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Bader Hamdan & Head of platform partnerships & Twilio \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Shay Howe & SVP of platform strategy & Active\-Campaign \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Heidi Williams & Head of platform engineering & Grammarly \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
  
    \mycell{How to Prioritize SaaS Product Integrations Roundtable}
    & Richard O'Connell & Director of product partnerships & Atlassian \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Amanda Groves & Director of product marketing & Crossbeam \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Chris Lavoie & Sr.\ technology partner manager & Gorgias \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Kabir Mathur & Head of product partnerships & Typeform  \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
    
    \mycell{How to Build a API and Integrations Roadmap}
    & Chloe Wu & Product manager & Gusto \\ \addlinespace 
    & India Anderson & Sr.\ manager, product management integrations & Avalara \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Deven Ravel & Head of technology partnerships & Reputation \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Matt Marum & Director of ISV alliances & SugarCRM \\  
    %\addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
    
   \mycell{Cross-functional collaboration in tech partnerships}
    & Roger Haas & Sr.\ manager of technology partnerships & Pantheon.io \\* 
    \addlinespace 
    & Jamie Boardman & Director of partnerships, product & Mailchimp \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Kenneth Marks & Associate Director of product management & Olo \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & John Greene & Director of engineering, integrations & Airship  \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
    
    \mycell{Advice for Building a Tech Partner Program}
    & Jaimie Fucillo & VP of Partnerships & Mindbody \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Daniel O'Leary & Director of Partnerships & Box \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Jake Wallace & Head of global technology partnerships & Trustpilot \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Elliot Smith & Head of partnerships & 6sense \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
        
    \mycell{How to Tackle Tech Partner Operations}
    & Megha Bhatt & Partnerships lead of operations \& strategy operations & Shopify \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Greg Mitchell & Partner programs and operations & Starburst \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Matt Irving & Sr.\ Manager of global partner programs \& strategy & WP Engine \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Manishi Singh & SVP of app orchestration & Spryker Systems \\  
    \addlinespace[2.5ex] %\midrule
    
    \mycell{How to Build a Platform UX Partners and Customers Love}
    & Richard Fortune & Product manager of platform experience & Xero \\ 
    \addlinespace 
    & Courtney George & Head of design for data & Amplitude \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Kirby Montgomery & VP of product leadership & C2FO \\ 
    \addlinespace  
    & Ashwini Sriram & Group product manager & Twilio  \\  
    
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```